# How were the Resistance able to survive in the future, up until Reese's timeline?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-terminator

Assuming Skynet was starting to update units, (T-800) being the latest in technology, how were they not all equipped with Infrared and thermal imaging CPUs? You would think advanced machines would be able to stake out any human anywhere at that point.

Answer (score 4):

Skynet is of very much the same opinion as you. Why won't they just die?!

> To Skynet, human stubbornness made no sense. They fought when logic told the synthetic intelligence they were beaten. They relentlessly poured out of the rubble like a bacterial plague, their patterns of counterattack clever and difficult to predict. And humans reproduced at an alarming rate, their sexual appetites evidently fanned high by the threat of total annihilation.
>
> Even though it took at least eight years before the human young could be made ready for battle, they were beginning to outpace Skynet’s manufacturing capabilities. And they were quickly learning to find the soft spots in the metal vanguard, decimating Skynet’s army of killing machines. Soon, there would be more human soldiers than nonhuman. The hyper-computer had miscalculated gravely on something it was still furiously analyzing: human will. So far, it had not come to a conclusion. And the war was grinding into its thirty-first year....
>
> <sub><sup>[T2: Judgement Day](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day_(Frakes_novel))</sup></sub>

The implication is that its fancy satellites, flying HK units, Devastators and Terminator units are proving less useful against an enemy that (mostly) hides underground and destroys any machines that come near.

Comment: Another question I may pose is how Skynet is able to get its equipment for making such machines. Assuming Skynet use to just be a factory of cybernetic organisms, and it went rogue to make whatever it had left; it would make sense that it was reaching a point where it would need to replenish its supply or just stop making certain units altogether.

Comment: @WantingAnswers - Skynet maintains a series of human-run work camps and mines. It stands to reason that it can get hold of pretty much any resources that existed before Judgement Day. That being said, the key element of an episode of the Sarah Connor Chronicles related to a Terminator traveling through time to hide supplies of a certain kind of metal that could be used to rapidly create more Terminators, so it's possible that certain things aren't that easy to come by any more.